# cant communicate with other computer using socket.io node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to play with node.js using socket.io

anyway, when using on my local network I get an error:

```
got heartbeat packet
   debug - cleared heartbeat timeout for client 4BMneKTWn1Qph1iMNbJf
   debug - set heartbeat interval for client 4BMneKTWn1Qph1iMNbJf
   debug - emitting heartbeat for client MqmuDptZ35RVawHKNbJl
   debug - websocket writing 2::
   debug - set heartbeat timeout for client MqmuDptZ35RVawHKNbJl
```

When Im using my local machine I can open multiple windows and it works.

I change the `index.html` to the right path and I can see the server log so that's good.

basically the issue is the computer that connect to my server/computer cant transmit his changes.

Thanks for all of you guys!

Answer (score 2):

hehe find the solution add to point to my computer using the ip on the index.html and the script.js.

hate those stupid mistakes.

hope I will help some one with it.